# How to run Apache Spark Source in C#

Tags: c#, apache-spark

I want to run apache spark source from the C# by converting the spark java/scala api into dll files. I have referred ikvm/ikvmc to convert spark jar files into dll files but couldn't get proper results. Is there any way to run the spark source in C#?

Please guide me to resolve this?

Apache Spark has given support to Java, Scala, R, Python languages to run spark. Is there is support for C# will be given in future?

Answer (score 9):

C# language binding for Apache Spark is now available through Mobius.

See https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius for more info.

Comment: Mobius development is deprecated. .NET for Apache Spark is the newer one https://github.com/dotnet/spark